# Using iterators as offset index

Tags: c++, syntax, listiterator

Apologies if this was already asked. I couldn't find an answer to that.
Is it legal to use an iterator as an offset index?
For example:

```
for (list<T> iterator::it = v2->vals.begin(); it!=v2->vals.end();++i) {
    v3.push_back(v2[it] + v1[it]);
}
```

where : const Vec& v2
and vals is a list in Vec class's protected.

Many thanks!

Comment: No it is not possible. you probably want `*it`.

Comment: @Jarod42 OP wants to use the iterator of one list as an index on a different list. That doesn't change the "No" part of your answer.

Comment: @AviGinsburg: As there is `++i` which seems to be a typo, `v1[it]` may also be one. Not sure what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly use iterators as indexes.

However, if you do want to use the iterators "position" in its container to have the index you want, you can do so with [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), i.e.:

```
unsigned int index = std::distance(v2.begin(), it);
//if it was the fifth element, index's value is 4.
```

Comment: I read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) that the requirements is InputIterator, not RandomAccessIterator. The relevant section in the standard is **24.4.4§5**.

Comment: Don't you mean "if it was the fifth element, index's value is **4**"?

Comment: @AviGinsburg Woops, indeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If `v1` and `v2` are instances of a custom data type, then yes it's possible, because you can then create an overloaded `operator[]` functions which takes the correct iterator types as arguments.

However it's not as easy as it seems for you, since at least `v2` seems to be a *pointer*, so you need to either dereference it first:

```
(*v2)[it]
```

or call the operator function explicitly:

```
v2->operator[](it)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But isn't the [] operator overloaded so that it automatically dereferences it?

Comment: @elti No, there's no standard overload of the `operator[]` that takes any kind of iterator and dereferences it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For parallel traversal of multiple containers, you can use Boost.Iterator's Zip Iterator :

```
std::transform(
    boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(begin(v1), begin(v2))),
    boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(  end(v1),   end(v2))),
    std::back_inserter(v3),
    [](boost::tuple<int const &, int const&> const &p) {
        return p.get<0>() + p.get<1>();
    }
);
```

I'm admittedly not really convinced by the syntax though. IMHO this library would benefit from some C++11/14 peppering.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I got what I was looking for.